# Android floating view (over other views)

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-layout

I've been messing around with this for a few days now, hopefully someone here can lend me a hand.

I have a simple two-column layout, the left side is a navigation bar with buttons, the right side is a content panel.  When the user taps one of the buttons (say, the third one down), I'd like to have a floating view aligned to the right of this button but floating on top of the content pane.  Here's a picture to illustrate what I mean:
[image: Layout]

Everything I've tried shoves the floating menu inside the navigation bar or inside the content panel, which is not what I want.  Any ideas?  Here's basically what I have so far:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
    >
        <FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
        >
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/button1_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
        >
            <ImageButton 
                android:id="@+id/button2_btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.14"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/navigation_bar"
    >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 fore the drawing :P

Comment: Dave, have you managed to implement this. I require to do something very simmilar so will be glad if you share some bits of your implementation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A FrameLayout allows you to have a view overlapping another view.  I'm not sure it makes sense to have them with only one child view, as you have in your example.  Try having a FrameLayout at the highest level, with your "static" view as the first child element, and the floating menu as the second child.

The [developer documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout) have a good overview the layout types, it might help you get started.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` also supports overlapping views.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` inherits from `FrameLayout`.

Comment: Link broken in Apr 2017, use [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) instead

Comment: @Cheryl the link is broken

Answer (score -12):

`RelativeLayout` is what you want.
`FrameLayout` must only have one child, and is therefore, usually, only used for a placeholder where other layouts come later (such as the main frame of the activity).
`AbsoluteLayout` is deprecated, and should not be used.

`RelativeLayout` allows the views to overlap, and allows doing, pretty much, anything you want.

Comment: FrameLayout absolutely can have multiple childs.