# Add floating views to be dragged

Tags: android, view, draggable

I already readed this [Android floating view (over other views)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268569/android-floating-view-over-other-views)

And I already know and did myself it to add Views in top of other views.

My problem now, is that I need to drag these Views around, and I don't have idea how to translate then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a TranslationAnimation but then the views would only be "displayed" at a different position. The click targets would remain in the same spot.

What you could try is to make create a bitmap of the view using bitmapCache, drag that around and when you drop it move the view to the new position either using absolute values for your LayoutParams or by having something like a gridview underneath it in whose cells you put the draged view. Kinda like its done in the launcher app. The views would snap into position this way.

Does this make sense ? Pobably not :)
It might also be possible to animate the margins in the LayoutParams and call requestLayout on the parent for each touchEvent... havent tried.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to point you to [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/) tutorial. I think its what you are searching about. :)

Comment: Not exactly, I already know how to read user input, I need to able the Views to drag around.