# ScrollView delivery touchEvent to child

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to achieve the effect like the follow pictures.When I scrolling the layout to the position like the second picture. If I scrolling continue, I want to drag the view down.
Sorry for my poor English, I hope everyone can understand it.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What you have tried to achieve this ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2268811/2660921 this?